# Мне необходимо получить названия столбцов в базе данных SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Мне нужно представить данные из базы данных в форме {'col_name1': 'значение', 'col_name2': 'значение'} **с помощью библиотеки sqlite3 на Python.** Как получить значение из таблицы я знаю, однако как получить название столбца я не понимаю. Используя `PRAGMA table_info('TEST')`, где 'TEST' - название моей таблицы, выводятся все данные, однако мне нужно получить лишь названия столбцов. Прошу у Вас помощи!

Comment: зачем тебе название столбца

Comment: @Lofectr Мне нужно представить данные из базы данных в форме {'col_name1': 'значение', 'col_name2': 'значение'}, а 'col_name1' и 'col_name2' это названия столбцов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну можно воспользоваться запросом:

`SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;` или `SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master;`

Поле *sql* таблицы *sqlite_master* содержит запрос которым таблица была создана, и его можно распарсить на нужные данные: название столбцов, тип столбцов, ограничения которые наложены на столбец. Но нужно учитывать, что запрос создавший нужную для анализа таблицу храниться в *sqlite_master* as-is то есть в первозданном виде, если там человек создавший исследуемую БД решил натыкать ненужных переносов строк, то все они там будут сохраненными. Даже комментарии которые были в коде создания таблицы будут там сохранены. По этому перед парсингом данных из этой таблицы следует очистить её от лишнего (лишние пробелы, переносы строк, возможные комментарии и та далее), а уже после этого можно проводить анализ.

p.s.: если вспомню ещё способы, то напишу)
p.p.s: так же в этой таблице храниться информация о созданных индексах, представлениях, триггерах и так далее, по этому имеет смысл указывать вместе с квалификатором отбора *WHERE type LIKE "table";*

Comment: спасибо огромное за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Из представленного Вами запроса `PRAGMA table_info("TEST")` можно просто убрать лишнюю информацию. Например

```
cur.execute('PRAGMA table_info("TEST")')
column_names = [i[1] for i in cur.fetchall()]
print(column_names)
```

Информация содержится в виде кортёжа (`номер столбца (с нуля)`, `название столбца`, `тип данных`, `может ли быть null`, `значение по умолчанию`, `является ли primary key`)